# How to add the same comment in the same Column name on different tables in the same db in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a db with a lot of tables in it. Some of these tables have columns with the exact same name (e.g. comment_id).

Is there a way (in sql) to add the same comment to the column with the same name in different tables (in the same db).

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Can you give an example? What have you tried so far?

Comment: Check for relationship between tables and insert based on Key

Comment: No.you could build alter statements for all tables via information.schema.columns

Comment: Up until now I go to each table manually and add the comment.
For example i go to the column example_id in sqlWorkBench , alter table and i add the comment in each table.
The tables are around 200. and the column example_id is in all of them. I want to write a script to put the same comment in the same column.

Comment: If's it a comment_id, wouldn't that mean that there's some "Comments" table where those comments are stored? Then those records in the tables could point to the same comment_id ? (although that idea seems kinda weird i.m.h.o.)

Comment: The comment_id is an example.

Comment: @LukStorms is correct .We know comment_id is one such example but it's better you make comments as a table with id and description .Then it will be easy to insert the ids in bulk.you can follow the same for other columns